# Monads in monad transformer context

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, monad-transformers

I have trouble gripping to monads and monad transformers. I have the
following contrived example (not compilable):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Reader

data State = State Int Int Int
type Foo = ReaderT State IO

readEither :: String -> Either String Int
readEither s = let p = reads s
           in case p of
               [] -> throwError "Could not parse"
               [(a, _)] -> return a

readEitherT :: IO (Either String Int)
readEitherT = let p s = reads s
          in runErrorT $ do
    l <- liftIO (getLine)
    readEither l

foo :: Foo Int
foo = do
  d <- liftIO $ readEitherT
  case d of
       Right dd -> return dd
       Left em -> do
     liftIO $ putStrLn em
     return (-1)

bar :: Foo String
bar = do
  liftIO $ getLine

defaultS = State 0 0 0
```

If I copy the functionality of readEither to readEitherT, it works, but I
have a nagging feeling that I can leverage the power of the existing
readEither function, but I can't figure out how. If I try to lift the
readEither in the readEitherT function, it lifts it to `ErrorT String IO
(Either String Int)` as it should. But I should somehow get it to `ErrorT
String IO Int`.

If I'm going to the wrong direction with this, what is the correct way to
handle errors which require IO (or other monads) and are to be called from
monadic context (see the `foo` function in the example)

**Edit:**
Apparently it was not clear what I was trying to do. Maybe the following function describes what and why I was wondering

```
maybePulseQuit :: Handle -> IO (Either String ())
maybePulseQuit h = runErrorT $ do
  f <- liftIO $ (communicate h "finished" :: IO (Either String Bool))
  (ErrorT . pure) f >>= \b → liftIO $ when b $ liftIO pulseQuit
```

This works, but is still ugly because of the binds. This is a lot clearer than the previous version which had case checking. Is this the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you need `ErrorT`. You can implement `readEitherT` like

```
readEitherT :: IO (Either String Int)
readEitherT = fmap readEither getLine
```

If you really need `ErrorT` for some reason, then you can create utility function `eitherToErrorT`:

```
eitherToErrorT = ErrorT . pure

readEitherT = runErrorT $ do
  l <- liftIO $ getLine
  eitherToErrorT $ readEither l
```

**[ADD]**
Maybe you just want to add `ErrorT` into your monad stack...

```
data State = State Int Int Int
type Foo = ErrorT String (ReaderT State IO)

runFoo :: Foo a -> State -> IO (Either String a)
runFoo foo s = runReaderT (runErrorT foo) s

doIt :: Int -> Foo Int
doIt i = if i < 0
            then throwError "i < 0"
            else return (i * 2)
```

Example:

```
*Main> runFoo (doIt 1 >>= doIt) (State 0 0 0)
Right 4
*Main> runFoo (doIt (-1) >>= doIt) (State 0 0 0)
Left "i < 0"
```

Comment: I was thinking for example doing try(foobar) inside ErrorT which would propagate the possible error within the ErrorT monad. (IO (Either e a))

Comment: I've added an example how to propagate error using `ErrorT`, maybe it will help